# Scalar field energy density not changing with expanding spacetime

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, lagrangian-formalism, metric-tensor, field-theory

Basically, I just want to know why this scalar field's energy density does not change, even though spacetime is expanding.

A general expanding cartesian metric is used:
$$
g_{00} = -1 $$ $$ 
g_{11} = a(t)^2$$ $$ 
g_{22} = a(t)^2$$ $$
g_{33} = a(t)^2$$

The following is a general scalar field oscillator in curved spacetime:
$$
L = -\dfrac{1}{2} g^{dc}∇_dΦ ∇_cΦ - \dfrac{1}{2} b^2 Φ^2
$$
We will consider a simple case where the scalar field is homogeneous and isotropic, so $Φ'(x) = Φ'(y) = Φ'(z) = 0$

This results in a single non-zero equation of motion:
$$-g_{00}Φ''(t) = -\dfrac{1}{2} b^2Φ(t)$$

The problem is, because $g_{00}$ is just -1, and not some function, the resulting EOM is not affected by the volumetric change of the metric due to $a(t)$.
$$Φ''(t) = -\dfrac{1}{2} b^2Φ(t)$$

The solution for $Φ(t)$ is clearly not a function of $a(t)$, and yet it represents a scalar field density (i.e. energy/volume).

If my math is correct, why can this scalar field retain its energy density?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your equation of motion is missing the Hubble friction term $3H\Phi'$ coming from $\nabla_m\nabla^m\Phi$ (since $\nabla$ is the covariant derivative), i.e. the equation of motion would be
$$
\Phi''+3H\Phi'+\partial_{\Phi}V=0~,
$$
where $H=a'/a$, $V=b^2\Phi^2/2$.

Comment: For completeness, it's worth noting that the scalar Laplacian for a given metric works out to be$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{|g|}} \frac{\partial}{\partial x^\mu} \left( \sqrt{|g|} g^{\mu \nu} \frac{\partial \Phi}{\partial x^\nu} \right).$$In this case $\sqrt{|g|} = a^3$, which explains where the $\dot{a}/a$ terms come from.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  All very helpful

Comment: When I have computed it myself, I obtained Φ″-3Φ′+∂Φ=0.   Is there a typo in your response?  Or did I miss something

Comment: @tertius should be plus. You can look it up in various cosmology  textbooks.